# Core 3.0 MVC Area route Not working in RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-routing

In asp.net core 2.2 MVC

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { Area = "Dashboard" });
```

Works properly.

But in Core 3.0 it not working. Area go as a query string like

```
http://localhost:1876/?Areas=Dashboard
```

My Configuration:

Startup Class

1. *ConfigureServices* Method

   ```
   services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
   ```
2. *Configure* Method

   ```
   app.UseMvc(routes =>
   {
       routes.MapRoute(
              name: "default",
              template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

       routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Area",
              template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
   });
   ```

Answer (score 3):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7772) that had been reported for 2.2 version, you don't need to use `option.EnableEndpointRouting = false` anymore. Plus, your area route config must go at first place, like this :

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Area",
       template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "default",
       template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

   });
```